# Android Studio compiler doesn't compile my AdsClass

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new class. It is **AdsClass.java**. I added no existence class to check if compiler see my class.

Android studio must tell me about compiler error like NoExistanceClass not found. But Android Studio tells that everything okay and it installed my app on Android device.

How can I force the compiler to compile AdsClass?

```
package org.cocos2dx.cpp;

public class AdsClass {

 public void showInterstitial() {
    NoExistanceClass my;
 }
}
```

My **AdsClass.java** path is

[image: My AdsClass.java path is]

Settings.gradle

```
include ':libcocos2dx'
project(':libcocos2dx').projectDir = new File(settingsDir,      '../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/libcocos2dx')
include ':mahjongDroid'
project(':mahjongDroid').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'app')
```

my left pane

[image]

Comment: are you using Gradle? Have you added that module to the `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: Give us a screenshot of what your project looks like in AndroidStudio, i.e. the project pane on the left

Comment: @Blundell, yes, I use Gradle.

Comment: There is a compile error in the AppActivity class, you need to fix that first so that the whole project can be built, then further errors might be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `org.cocos2dx.cpp` package outside `main/java` and by default Gradle default java source directory is `src/main/java` so you can add your package to build path or there are few solutions as:

1. Add your new java package source to build path in `app/build.gradle`(app) using

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 29
       buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

       defaultConfig {
          // ...
       }

       sourceSets { // add package to path
           main.java.srcDirs += 'src/org/cocos2dx/cpp'
       }

   }
   ```
2. Or, you can move `org.cocos2dx.cpp` package/files inside `src/main/java` package
3. You can create a library module under your repo.

---

Example:

```
sourceSets { // add package to path
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/org'
}
```

[image]

Comment: To approve a changes I should clean a project.

Comment: @Voloda2 yes, normal gradle sync or rebuild should work though it should compile and show changes like files in `main` package